# Can I marry an Italian citizen if I am in Italy on an overstayed tourist visa?

Tags: visa, us-citizens, marriage, italy, overstay

So I am an American citizen in Italy with my Italian girlfriend whom I plan to marry. I came to Italy on a Schengen tourist visa but I have overstayed the visa by 40 days. Is it possible to get married here in Italy on a visa overstay and be able to stay here in Italy?

Comment: How far down the wedding planning process are you? https://wise.com/gb/blog/getting-married-in-italy-guide

Comment: We have the Nulla Osta from my embassy but I have to go to the local police station to have it verified. After that we can go back to the town hall and hopefully start the process. I am just afraid they will not verify the Nulla Osta or let us go through with the marriage because I am overstayed the visa. I was reading your link that you provided however and it mentions; "A foreign national marrying an Italian citizen does not need to have a visa to hold a wedding in Italy.". So hopefully that is true. Thanks for your help.

Comment: IANAL but I would suppose ‘does not need to have a visa’ refers to a marriage visa or similar (required by many countries). If I were you I would contact an immigration lawyer for advice ASAP, your overstay is already a breach of immigration rules and that could have serious consequences if not handled correctly. As a general rule I would say getting married anywhere in the world requires the person to be *legally* in the country where they want to marry.

Comment: Ah ok, yes you make some good points there. I will try to contact a lawyer. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Traveller there are many places that pay no attention to immigration status of marrying couples, the US included, and, given the material you link to, Italy seems to be among them.  I seriously doubt that there's anything standing in the way of Kent's marrying and remaining in Italy.  Certainly, once the marriage is concluded, there is no obstacle to staying.  Kent: how long have you and your girlfriend been together?  If your relationship is "durable" (a term defined in EU law but interpreted according to Italian law), you might even be able to stay without marrying.

Comment: Just an update; I did contact an immigration lawyer and he advised me that I only need a Nulla Osta and my passport. The visa overstay shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Germany separates things. To get married in Germany, one partner must be resident in the district of the registry office (and the wedding must be legal according to German law and each of the partners laws), but they don’t care about the visa. But if any other government office has the right and desire to remove you, having your wedding planned for tomorrow will also be ignored and won’t help you.